# Swifty Dropbox sign in via access token

Tags: ios, swift, dropbox, dropbox-api

I created new account and uploaded some pictures. I also created Access Token.
Users haven't dropbox account and I want to display these pictures in my application. Can I do this without login page?

It works good with login page:

```
DropboxClientsManager.authorizeFromController(UIApplication.shared,
                                                      controller: self,
                                                      openURL: { (url: URL) -> Void in
                                                      UIApplication.shared.openURL(url)
        })
let client = DropboxClientsManager.authorizedClient
```

But doesn't work with access token only:

```
let client = DropboxClient.init(accessToken: "...")
```

But it doesn't work:

```
client?.files.download(path: "/pics")
            .response { response, error in
                if let response = response {
                    let responseMetadata = response.0
                    print(responseMetadata)
                    let fileContents = response.1
                    print(fileContents)
                } else if let error = error {
                    print(error)
                }
            }
            .progress { progressData in
                print(progressData)
        }
```

I got error: **Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-999 "cancelled" UserInfo={NSErrorFailingURLKey=https://api-content.dropbox.com/2/files/download, NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=https://api-content.dropbox.com/2/files/download, NSLocalizedDescription=cancelled}**

Comment: You have to login/authorize at least once, then i think you can preserve this authorized client and consume at some later point in time.

Comment: My application contains some images. Users haven't dropbox account and I must show these images in my application. Can I do this without login page?

Comment: Perhaps you want to share file(s) with users: https://www.dropbox.com/en/help/20

Comment: How can I download photo in code without login page?

Comment: [Cross-linking for reference: https://www.dropboxforum.com/t5/API-support/Sign-In-via-access-token-without-login-page/m-p/209990#M10451 ]

Comment: Have a look at DropboxClientsManager.swift.  There are some methods in there that aren't public but I think are going to be relevant.  Perhaps you can at least test with that @testable import SwiftyDropbox